# Producer and Consumer Optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, optimization, semaphore

I am writing a C++ program in Qt that has an OnReceive(int value) event. It captures and push_back integer values into the std::vector. On another worker thread I have access to this vector and I can set a semaphore to wait for 20 values and then I can process them.

I want to do some optimization.

My question is how can I segment my buffer or vector into 3 parts of 0-4, 5-10, 11-19  so for example, as soon as 5 values are available in the vector (e.g 0 to 4), the second worker start to process them while the first thread still continue to get the rest of values?

by this way I wanna have an overlap between my threads. so they don't need to be run in serial.

Thank you.

Comment: Search the internet for "double buffering".

Answer (score 1):

Use a wait-free ring buffer.

Boost claims to have [one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html)

Note it is in the lock free folder but all methods claim to be thread safe and wait-free.